# Quinones - Radical Scavengers

Tags: organic-chemistry, radicals

In the textbook of "A Guidebook to Mechanism in Organic Chemistry" by Peter Sykes, it is mentioned that **peroxides** are *radical sources* and **quinones** are *radical absorbers or scavengers*, but it had no explanation, and quick search gave results about **HALS**, but not about quinones. Also I understand that peroxides can act as radical sources due to homolytic cleavage and its *'O-O'* bond energy being very low, around 140 kJmol^-1. But can you explain how quinones are good radical scavengers? Also its mechanism, if any, would be appreciated.

Comment: Look up the redox chemistry of these compounds, that should be covered in many basic chemistry books.

Comment: Might I ask the reason for downvote?

Comment: @Martin, Also, I searched in L.G.Wade before asking, and there was no mention

Comment: HALS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindered_amine_light_stabilizers?

Comment: I am not a particular fan of libre texts, but the following has quite a bit of what is needed to understand this: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Basic_Principles_of_Organic_Chemistry_(Roberts_and_Caserio)/26%3A_More_on_Aromatic_Compounds/26.02%3A_Quinones